# Fade in/out and pause on mouse over with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've wrote a quick jQuery snippet to automatically fades in/out a set of div's at a pre-set interval. My code looks like this:

HTML

```
<div id="container">
<div>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
<div>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
<div>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function InOut(elem)
{
elem.delay()
 .fadeIn(600)
 .delay(5000)
 .fadeOut(600,
     function(){
        if(elem.next().length > 0) 
          { InOut(elem.next()); }
        else
          { InOut(elem.siblings(':first')); }

      }
    );
}

$('#container div').hide();
InOut($('#container div:first'));
```

Is it possible to have this effect pause when a user mouseover's one of the  elements within the #container? I've made several attempts with no luck.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
function InOut(elem)
{
elem.delay()
 .fadeIn(600)
 .delay(500)
 .fadeOut(600,
     function(){
        if(elem.next().length > 0) 
          { InOut(elem.next()); }
        else
          { InOut(elem.siblings(':first')); }

      }
    )
  .mouseover(function(){
        $(this).stop(true, false);
    })
  .mouseout(function(){
        InOut($(this));
    });
}

$('#container div').hide();
InOut($('#container div:first'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Seems to work on the first mouseover, then on subsequent mouseovers, the div elements start stacking under each other and fading in/out at random. Any ideas?

Comment: check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/two7s_clash/XCxbL/1/ eventually causes multiple divs to show.